# При передаче параметра возникает ошибка "идентификатор ch не определен"

Tags: c++

```
int menu(char ch) {
    printf("1. Цикл for/n");
    printf("2.Цикл while\n");
    printf("3.test \n");
    printf(" Выберите пункт меню: ");

    do { /* Считываем символ с клавиатуры */
        switch (ch) {
            case '1':
                fort();
                break;
            case '2':
                wfhile();
                break;
            case '3':
                test();
                break;
        }
    } while (ch != '1' && ch != '2' && ch != '3');
}


int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");
    menu(ch);
}
```

Не могу передать параметр функции menu, компилятор ругается на то, что идентификатор ch не определен.

Comment: В функции `main()` он действительно не определён. Приведите код в текстовом виде

Comment: Не в виде ссылки, а в виде текста

Comment: При чем здесь передача по ссылке?

Comment: правильнее сказать передача массива в качестве параметра

Comment: Скорее всего у Вас не определен в программе char ch. Вам честно об этом говорит транслятор. Вы определите char ch где-нибудь, и все будет хорошо.

Comment: Да тут и массива нет.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо @pepsicoca1
Сделал глобальную переменную и все заработало.

Comment: Эмм, а глобальную обязательно?

Comment: Ну вот и славно.